# Expectation of power spectrum for nonorthogonal wavelets

Tags: wavelet, power-spectral-density, orthogonal-signals

I'm working through ["A Practical Guide to Wavelet Analysis"](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/1520-0477%281998%29079%3C0061%3AAPGTWA%3E2.0.CO%3B2) by Torrence and Compo, and I am confused about section 3d ("Wavelet Power Spectrum").

Let $x_n$ denote the signal, sampled at increments $\delta t$; $\hat{x}_k$ its Fourier transform; $\psi$ the (normalized) mother wavelet, so that the amplitude of the wavelet transform at scale $s$ centered at $n\delta t$ is given by
$$
W_n(s) = \sum_k \hat{x}_k \hat{\psi}^*(s \omega_k)e^{i\omega_k n\delta t} 
$$
There's some fiddling with constants here, but I understand this so far.

Then, they write that, for a white noise signal, $\mathbb{E}|W_n(s)|^2 = N \mathbb{E}|\hat{x}_k|^2 = \sigma^2$. Trying to work through this: 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}|W_n(s)|^2 &= \mathbb{E}\left|\sum \hat{x}_k \hat{\psi}^*(s \omega_k)e^{i\omega_k n\delta t}\right|^2
\end{align}
I see that *if the wavelets are orthogonal*, this works out nicely, where you can write
$$
\mathbb{E}\left|\sum \hat{x}_k \hat{\psi}^*(s \omega_k)e^{i\omega_k n\delta t}\right|^2 = \sum |\hat{\psi}(s \omega_k)|^2\mathbb{E}|\hat{x}_k|^2
= \frac{\sigma^2}{N}\sum |\hat{\psi}(s \omega_k)|^2
$$
However, the authors clearly state they are **not** working with orthogonal wavelets specifically here, so I am unsure how they get their white noise result.